# Directives that can communicate with other directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble figuring out how to have one directive trigger an event within a different directive

Say I have the following 2 directives

```
project.directive('ActionButton', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        orderId: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '/scripts/templates/directive-templates/order-action-button.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.doAction = function()  {
            // I want to trigger 'scope.refreshOrderDetails' in my other directive from here
        }
    }
}

project.directive('OrderView', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        orderId: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '/scripts/templates/directive-templates/order-view.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.refreshOrderDetails = function()  {
            // data is refreshed here
        }
    }
}
```

And I use my directives like this

```
<ca-action-button order-id="{{orderId}}"></ca-order-action-button>

<ca-order-view order-id="{{orderId}}"></ca-order-details>
```

Where ca-order-details initially populates with data, but needs refreshed when a ca-order-action-button event is fired.

The action button will be loaded up with many doActions (it is a button dropdown with multiple actions), and there are going to be a few different OrderView type directives, each with it's own set of data needing refreshed upon different triggers

Comment: Seems like you need to use a parent controller for both these directives communicate through, rather than by using events (which can get unwieldy, especially when you have multiple sets of directives on a page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by broadcasting and listening for events:

In `ca-order-action-button`:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('event', { id: 12345 });
```

In `ca-order-details`:

```
$scope.$on('event', function (event, data) { console.log(data.id); });
```

Comment: I recommend that ca-order-details subscribe to the event on its scope rather than on $rootScope. That way when the scope is destroyed the even handler won't be hanging around.

Comment: @JohnBledsoe yep. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You're going wrong. Directives' link function should only be used to perform DOM transformations. I would like to use controllers and $rootScope for events.

```
project.directive('ActionButton', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        orderId: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '/scripts/templates/directive-templates/order-action-button.html',
    controller: 'ActionButtonCtrl'
  };
});

project.directive('OrderView', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          orderId: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: '/scripts/templates/directive-templates/order-view.html',
      controller: 'OrderViewCtrl'
  }
});

project.controller('ActionButtonCtrl',
['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.doAction = function() {
    $rooScope.$emit('refreshOrder', $scope.orderId);
  };
}]);

project.controller('OrderViewCtrl',
['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  var deregFn = $rootScope.$on('refreshOrder', function(orderId) {
    // refresh order details here
  });

  // Once scope is destroyed - cleanup
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    deregfn();
  });
}]);
```

Comment: It makes sense, I've updated these directives to utilize controller function rather than link functions. Thanks for the tip!